# How to directly reference a block of html defined in ng-template in angular?

Tags: angular

How to directly reference a block of html defined in `ng-template`?

To reference `filterOfDiv`, I have to use `*ngIf` directive and always set the condition to `true`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='true; then filterOfDiv'></ng-container>
<ng-template #filterOfDiv>
  <div class="flex-column row-space filter-container">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="company1"><label for="company1" class="label-input">company1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="company2"><label for="company2" class="label-input">company2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Is there a way to reference `filterOfDiv` directly, like:

```html
<ng-container filterOfDiv></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#how-to-use) directive

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterOfDiv"></ng-container>
```